# Having trouble building new laravel project with sail and docker

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu-20.04, laravel-sail

I'm creating a new laravel project using docker and sail, i'm on Windows 10, I have enabled WSL 2 and all that was required in the docs, but after I create the laravel project in the ubuntu shell (Ubuntu 20.04), and build sail using the following commands

```
cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up
```

I get the following:

```
#7 737.3 0 upgraded, 123 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
#7 737.3 Need to get 81.6 MB of archives.
#7 737.3 After this operation, 309 MB of additional disk space will be used.
#7 737.3 Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 liblocale-gettext-perl amd64 1.07-4build1 [16.9 kB]
#7 737.4 Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php-common all 2:84+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [16.3 kB]
#7 737.6 Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 bsdextrautils amd64 2.36.1-7ubuntu2 [81.6 kB]
#7 737.8 Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libuchardet0 amd64 0.0.7-1 [68.0 kB]
#7 738.0 Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-common amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1047 kB]
#7 738.0 Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 groff-base amd64 1.22.4-6 [864 kB]
#7 744.5 Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libpipeline1 amd64 1.5.3-1 [27.8 kB]
#7 744.5 Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 man-db amd64 2.9.4-2 [1154 kB]
#7 751.0 Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 psmisc amd64 23.4-2build1 [117 kB]
#7 751.4 Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libmemcached11 amd64 1.0.18-4.2ubuntu2 [83.5 kB]
#7 751.7 Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libargon2-1 amd64 0~20171227-0.2build21.04.0 [19.2 kB]
#7 751.8 Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libelf1 amd64 0.183-8 [47.3 kB]
#7 751.9 Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-0 amd64 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1 [1301 kB]
#7 755.8 Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-data all 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1 [5528 B]
#7 755.9 Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libicu67 amd64 67.1-6ubuntu2 [8619 kB]
#7 760.2 Get:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-igbinary amd64 3.2.6+2.0.8-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [132 kB]
#7 761.0 Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-msgpack amd64 2.1.2+0.5.7-6+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [27.2 kB]
#7 761.5 Get:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-memcached amd64 3.1.5+2.2.0-9+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [44.0 kB]
#7 762.0 Get:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-pcov amd64 1.0.9-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [15.8 kB]
#7 762.5 Get:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-redis amd64 5.3.4+4.3.0-2+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [151 kB]
#7 767.5 Get:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-curl amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [33.2 kB]
#7 768.0 Get:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-mysql amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [121 kB]
#7 769.9 Get:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-swoole amd64 4.7.0-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [781 kB]
#7 778.3 Get:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-xdebug amd64 3.0.4+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [499 kB]
#7 780.0 Get:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libxml2 amd64 2.9.12+dfsg-0+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [769 kB]
#7 782.2 Get:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-opcache amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [459 kB]
#7 787.5 Get:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-readline amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [12.6 kB]
#7 789.1 Get:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-cli amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1470 kB]
#7 789.8 Err:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-cli amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
#7 789.8   Undetermined Error [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
#7 790.1 Get:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php-json all 2:8.0+84+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [6988 B]
#7 790.4 Get:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-xml amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [98.0 kB]
#7 791.2 Get:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-bcmath amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [15.6 kB]
#7 791.6 Get:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-dev amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [464 kB]
#7 799.2 Get:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-gd amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [27.6 kB]
#7 800.7 Get:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-imap amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [31.4 kB]
#7 804.3 Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 shared-mime-info amd64 2.0-1 [435 kB]
#7 805.4 Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 xdg-user-dirs amd64 0.17-2ubuntu2 [48.3 kB]
#7 805.5 Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 gettext-base amd64 0.21-3ubuntu2 [39.5 kB]
#7 805.6 Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libsigsegv2 amd64 2.13-1ubuntu1 [14.2 kB]
#7 805.6 Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 m4 amd64 1.4.18-5 [200 kB]
#7 806.1 Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 autoconf all 2.69-14 [293 kB]
#7 807.6 Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 autotools-dev all 20180224.1+nmu1 [39.4 kB]
#7 807.7 Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 automake all 1:1.16.3-2ubuntu1 [552 kB]
#7 809.0 Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 autopoint all 0.21-3ubuntu2 [422 kB]
#7 810.0 Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 binutils-common amd64 2.36.1-6ubuntu1 [217 kB]
#7 810.6 Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libbinutils amd64 2.36.1-6ubuntu1 [584 kB]
#7 811.8 Err:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-imap amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
#7 811.8   Undetermined Error [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
#7 812.1 Get:46 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-intl amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [123 kB]
#7 812.6 Get:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libctf-nobfd0 amd64 2.36.1-6ubuntu1 [97.8 kB]
#7 812.8 Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libctf0 amd64 2.36.1-6ubuntu1 [95.0 kB]
#7 812.9 Get:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-ldap amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [28.8 kB]
#7 813.5 Get:50 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-mbstring amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [394 kB]
#7 813.5 Get:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu amd64 2.36.1-6ubuntu1 [1830 kB]
#7 817.4 Get:52 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-pgsql amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [55.0 kB]
#7 819.1 Get:53 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-soap amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [117 kB]
#7 820.3 Get:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 binutils amd64 2.36.1-6ubuntu1 [3388 B]
#7 820.5 Get:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 gcc-10-base amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1 [20.1 kB]
#7 820.6 Get:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libisl23 amd64 0.23-1build1 [661 kB]
#7 823.0 Get:57 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libmpfr6 amd64 4.1.0-3build1 [1400 kB]
#7 826.6 Get:58 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libmpc3 amd64 1.2.0-1build1 [44.1 kB]
#7 826.7 Get:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 cpp-10 amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1 [8612 kB]
#7 830.7 Err:53 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-soap amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
#7 830.7   Undetermined Error [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
#7 831.0 Get:60 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-sqlite3 amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [28.2 kB]
#7 831.5 Get:61 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-zip amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [23.7 kB]
#7 853.2 Get:62 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 cpp amd64 4:10.3.0-1ubuntu1 [27.7 kB]
#7 853.3 Get:63 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 libcc1-0 amd64 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04 [48.8 kB]
#7 853.4 Get:64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 libgomp1 amd64 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04 [107 kB]
#7 853.8 Get:65 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 libitm1 amd64 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04 [26.4 kB]
#7 853.8 Get:66 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 libatomic1 amd64 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04 [9236 B]
#7 854.2 Get:67 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 libasan6 amd64 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04 [2139 kB]
#7 861.4 Get:68 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 liblsan0 amd64 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04 [893 kB]
#7 863.6 Get:69 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 libtsan0 amd64 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04 [2090 kB]
#7 869.2 Get:70 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 libubsan1 amd64 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04 [844 kB]
#7 873.1 Get:71 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 libquadmath0 amd64 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04 [146 kB]
#7 880.2 Get:72 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libgcc-10-dev amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1 [2337 kB]
#7 887.9 Get:73 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 gcc-10 amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1 [17.5 MB]
#7 939.8 Get:74 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 gcc amd64 4:10.3.0-1ubuntu1 [5212 B]
#7 939.9 Get:75 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libstdc++-10-dev amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1 [1754 kB]
#7 944.5 Get:76 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 g++-10 amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1 [9803 kB]
#7 975.0 Get:77 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 g++ amd64 4:10.3.0-1ubuntu1 [1608 B]
#7 975.2 Get:78 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 make amd64 4.3-4ubuntu1 [167 kB]
#7 975.7 Get:79 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libdpkg-perl all 1.20.9ubuntu1 [232 kB]
#7 976.3 Get:80 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 lto-disabled-list all 7 [11.9 kB]
#7 976.4 Get:81 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 dpkg-dev all 1.20.9ubuntu1 [937 kB]
#7 978.9 Get:82 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 build-essential amd64 12.8ubuntu3 [4640 B]
#7 979.0 Get:83 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libdebhelper-perl all 13.3.4ubuntu1 [61.1 kB]
#7 979.3 Get:84 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libtool all 2.4.6-15 [161 kB]
#7 979.9 Get:85 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 dh-autoreconf all 20 [16.1 kB]
#7 980.1 Get:86 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libarchive-zip-perl all 1.68-1 [90.2 kB]
#7 980.5 Get:87 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libsub-override-perl all 0.09-2 [9532 B]
#7 980.7 Get:88 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl all 1.11.0-1 [17.0 kB]
#7 980.9 Get:89 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 dh-strip-nondeterminism all 1.11.0-1 [5236 B]
#7 981.0 Get:90 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libdw1 amd64 0.183-8 [225 kB]
#7 981.6 Get:91 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 debugedit amd64 1:0.1-0ubuntu2 [39.7 kB]
#7 981.8 Get:92 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 dwz amd64 0.14-1 [98.1 kB]
#7 982.2 Get:93 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 gettext amd64 0.21-3ubuntu2 [825 kB]
#7 984.8 Get:94 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 intltool-debian all 0.35.0+20060710.5 [24.9 kB]
#7 985.0 Get:95 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 po-debconf all 1.0.21+nmu1 [233 kB]
#7 985.6 Get:96 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 debhelper all 13.3.4ubuntu1 [920 kB]
#7 987.8 Get:97 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libfakeroot amd64 1.25.3-1.1ubuntu2 [28.1 kB]
#7 988.0 Get:98 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 fakeroot amd64 1.25.3-1.1ubuntu2 [62.9 kB]
#7 988.6 Get:99 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libalgorithm-diff-perl all 1.201-1 [41.8 kB]
#7 988.8 Get:100 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl amd64 0.04-6build1 [11.4 kB]
#7 988.9 Get:101 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libalgorithm-merge-perl all 0.08-3 [12.0 kB]
#7 989.1 Get:102 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libarchive-cpio-perl all 0.10-1.1 [9928 B]
#7 989.2 Get:103 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 mlock amd64 8:2007f~dfsg-7 [12.0 kB]
#7 989.4 Get:104 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 libc-client2007e amd64 8:2007f~dfsg-7 [578 kB]
#7 990.8 Get:105 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libfile-fcntllock-perl amd64 0.22-3build5 [33.1 kB]
#7 991.0 Get:106 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libltdl7 amd64 2.4.6-15 [38.8 kB]
#7 991.2 Get:107 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libltdl-dev amd64 2.4.6-15 [162 kB]
#7 991.7 Get:108 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libsys-hostname-long-perl all 1.5-2 [11.5 kB]
#7 991.8 Get:109 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libmail-sendmail-perl all 0.80-1.1 [22.7 kB]
#7 992.0 Get:110 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libonig5 amd64 6.9.6-1 [146 kB]
#7 992.4 Get:111 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libpcre2-16-0 amd64 10.36-2ubuntu5 [189 kB]
#7 993.0 Get:112 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libpcre2-32-0 amd64 10.36-2ubuntu5 [179 kB]
#7 993.5 Get:113 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libpcre2-posix2 amd64 10.36-2ubuntu5 [5996 B]
#7 993.6 Get:114 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libpcre2-dev amd64 10.36-2ubuntu5 [686 kB]
#7 995.2 Get:115 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 libpq5 amd64 13.4-0ubuntu0.21.04.1 [116 kB]
#7 995.8 Get:116 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libsodium23 amd64 1.0.18-1 [150 kB]
#7 996.3 Get:117 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 libssl-dev amd64 1.1.1j-1ubuntu3.5 [1586 kB]
#7 1000.5 Get:118 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 libxslt1.1 amd64 1.1.34-4 [152 kB]
#7 1001.1 Get:119 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 libzip4 amd64 1.7.3-1ubuntu1 [50.7 kB]
#7 1001.3 Get:120 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64 php-pear all 1:1.10.9+submodules+notgz-1.1ubuntu1.1 [287 kB]
#7 1002.0 Get:121 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 pkg-config amd64 0.29.2-1ubuntu1 [46.2 kB]
#7 1002.2 Get:122 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 shtool all 2.0.8-10 [122 kB]
#7 1002.7 Get:123 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 pkg-php-tools all 1.40 [28.0 kB]
#7 1002.8 EFetched 80.0 MB in 4min 26s (301 kB/s)
#7 1002.8 : Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php8.0/php8.0-cli_8.0.11-1%2bubuntu21.04.1%2bdeb.sury.org%2b1_amd64.deb  Undetermined Error [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
#7 1002.8 E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php8.0/php8.0-imap_8.0.11-1%2bubuntu21.04.1%2bdeb.sury.org%2b1_amd64.deb  Undetermined Error [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
#7 1002.8 E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php8.0/php8.0-soap_8.0.11-1%2bubuntu21.04.1%2bdeb.sury.org%2b1_amd64.deb  Undetermined Error [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
#7 1002.8 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C     && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev        php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd        php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached        php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring        php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap        php8.0-intl php8.0-readline php8.0-pcov        php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap        php8.0-redis php8.0-swoole php8.0-xdebug     && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -     && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*]: exit code: 100
ERROR: Service 'laravel.test' failed to build : Build failed
```

The issue seems to be around

```
#7 830.7 Err:53 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 php8.0-soap amd64 8.0.11-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
#7 830.7   Undetermined Error [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
```

I've tried removing all the containers, volumes and images from docker, and re-doing the whole process again, to no avail.

I've also tried using sudo before the command

```
cd example-app && sudo ./vendor/bin/sail up
```

but the same result.

---

Comment: Did you change your Dockerfile? It seems the problem lies there.

Comment: Hey, I have the same issue, did you fix it?

Comment: @AmirRezaM75 Nope. I had to eventually make a VM for linux, and i just setup docker there. The best guess I have is that it is your firewall or something blocking those assets from downloading..

Comment: @Commongrate I try that next day and it was successful. pretty sure it was ppa connection issue